# How the SVN handle the file access mode change?

Tags: svn

How the SVN handle the file access mode change?

For example:

I have a file foo.txt and its access mode is 644. Now I change it to 755 and use `svn diff`, I got nothing. It looks like the SVN dosen't think anything change about that file. Then how could I generate patch for that case?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure SVN doesn't (and *can't*, really) care about file permissions.  They're almost by necessity going to differ between working copies, in order to make the files usable by whoever checked them out.  (If file permissions were preserved, and someone committed some files as root, you'd be kinda screwed.)  About the best you'll likely be able to do is set the `svn:executable` property on a file using `svn propset`.

Answer (score 4):

svn uses properties to maintain the executable bit.  Do this:

```
svn propset svn:executable '*' <file>
```

Comment: And aside from read-only for files with `svn:needs-lock` set, this is the *only* permission that SVN "manages".

Answer (score 0):

SVN doesn't really pay attention to file permissions.  About the only thing you can do in this regard is set the `svn:executable` property on a file; see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s02.html.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it kinda does pay attention to them, just not their changes. I just had a case where i first commited a file with mode 644. After 'chmod 755 ...', svn didn't pick up the change. So i deleted the file from svn and re-added it with 755 mode. Subsequent checkouts of that file properly replicated the new mode. So, deleting and re-adding works. You do lose the file commit history and timeline.